# Chrome save as pdf for HTML Table with background color

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-table, pdf-generation

When I display a table in HTML I am using for CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

thead {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: var(--c);
}

thead > tr {
    line-height: 3.6rem !important;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
}
thead th {
    position:relative;
}
```

It produces something that looks like this:

[image: Table in Browser]

Now if I goto print in Chrome v73 and try Save to PDF the resultant PDF has something like this:

[image: Table after Save to PDF]

That is, it has created vertical cell outlines. It seems Opera, Firefox and Safari also produce the same so it must be something to do with the PDF rendering.

Anyone seen this issue before or know a solution?